# pymc5 - how to get prediction from new features

Tags: regression, prediction, bayesian, sampling, pymc

I'm exploring [pymc5](/questions/tagged/pymc5) package. I have built a simple model:

```py
model = pm.Model()

with model:
    response_mean = []
        for element in elements:
        xx           = df[element].values
        coeff        = pm.HalfNormal(element, sigma = 2)
        retention    = pm.Beta(element, alpha=3, beta=3)
        contribution = pm.Deterministic(element, (xx*retention*coeff))
        response_mean.append(contribution)

        sigma        = pm.HalfNormal('sigma', sigma=1)
        likelihood   = pm.Normal("likelihood",
                                  mu       = sum(response_mean),
                                  sigma    = sigma,
                                  observed = target)

with model:
    idata = pm.sample(return_inferencedata=True, tune= 1000)
```

for a specific element I get the posterior with this code:

```py
temp      = idata.posterior[element]
mean_temp = np.mean(temp, axis=(0,1))
```

Now I would like to get a new posterior or better a prediction starting from a new input array instead of `xx` (ie `xx_new`)

Probably I'm missing something... :(

Should I re-run a sample?

I tried with:

```py
with basic_model:
    p = pm.sample_posterior_predictive(idata, var_names=xx_new)
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance